# VBA to reference currently selected multi-cell range?

Tags: excel, vba

I can post some code, but my question is so simple I don’t think that’s needed.  I think I’m just struggling to know what to google.

I want to select (with my mouse) a range of multiple contiguous cells all in the same row and then execute a subroutine that will have a way to reference all the cells in that selected range. Is there a built in method for that? Something like:

```
Worksheet.ActiveRange(1,1).Value2
```

would reference the first cell and then

```
Worksheet.ActiveRange(1,2).Value2
```

would reference the second cell.

Or

```
MyFunction(Worksheet.ActiveRange)
```

Comment: So you're trying to use `Selection.Areas`? Or just `Selection`?

Comment: What do you mean by the **"built in method"**?

Comment: @Gene I mean “method” as in function or subroutine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the cells are contiguous, use `Selection`.

If the cells are not all contiguous, loop through `Selection.Areas`.

Since `Selection` may not necessarily be a `Range`, you can test for that first:

```
If TypeOf Selection Is Range Then...
```

You can also use [`Application.InputBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox) to get the range from user selection.